# How to search & replace text with my exact input letter case?

Tags: microsoft-word

Say I have a file:

```
Text text TEXT
```

I search for `text` and replace it with `worD`. The output will be:

```
WorD worD WORD
```

How do I make it to be

```
worD worD worD
```

?

Comment: Holy crap. Someone seems to consider that behavior a feature...

Answer (score 0):

As long as the text is short, you could use placeholders and have it match for upper and lower case like `[xX]` for a single character.

Applied to your case, that's

```
[Tt][Ee][Xx][Tt]
```

Screnshot from a German system:

[image: Screenshot]

If the text becomes longer, you might try some characters and a `*` like:

```
[Tt]*[Tt]
```

This will not only replace *Text*, but also *Toast* and *Teapot*.

Comment: is this regex? Typically my string are all complicated, like this: `Ng%C3%B4n%20t%E1%BB%AB%20%C4%91%C3%A2u%20m%C3%A0%20c%C3%B3%3F`

Comment: @Ooker, It's not regex in the sense usually understood today. IMO it is simpler for everyone not to refer to it as such. There's a helpful description of Word's wildcard find feature at https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm , although even that does not describe all of Word's quirks in this area. (When this syntax first arrived in Word, most regexes out there were much simpler than they are today and it would have made more sense to call Word's a regex.)